# Volley, authToken and AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, blocking, nonblocking, android-volley

I want to call my REST-API with an authToken, which I retrieve by calling the [AccountManager's](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html) getAuthToken method with a callback. After that I use Volley to communicate with my server and again have an Error and SuccessListener. This makes my code pretty messy...

So my question is: Would you recommend to use AsyncTask with getBlockingAuthToken and a blocking volley request instead of my previous approach?

Comment: same Topic in stackoverflow :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26141711/asynchronous-account-authentication-with-volley I'm having the same problem, did you find any solution?

Comment: No, I did not find a solution. Sorry!